# In Android, how to use a timer such that once the time is up, the application will say "time over"?

Tags: java, android, timer, timertask

So, in my application, it's like ,

1. A task is to performed within a given time interval
2. If the task is performed within the timer's time limit , then i want to add say t seconds to the timer
3. Then again i want to perform step 2.
4. If the task is not performed within the timer's time limit , then the application will say, something like "Sorry, time's up".

How to do it? Please help me with required APIs and how to use them.

Comment: `Handler.postDelayed()`? And maybe also `removeCallbacks` or whatever it was so that you can re-add the thing with different delay.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a  `CountDownTimer`, check here for more details : [Android documentation for CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Comment: It explains how to perform a task within a time interval. But how to add more time to the timer ?

Comment: Use a variable say `countDownTime` with initial value for countdown in the CountDownTimer constructor and update `countDownTime` with new value in `onFinish()` and start it again as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

use CountDownTimer for to take aaction after time is over

```
new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
       textView.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000); 
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        textView.setText("succcess"); //or textView.setText("Failed");
    }

}.start();
```